# Traversing 2 lists in play?

Tags: sql, list, playframework

I wanted to merge two lists and display the output in the front end using play!. The list is a resultset of an SQL query. I have two lists as I'm running two queries, and i want to merge the two lists and display in the UI. I cannot use the **INNER JOIN** because of performance issues. Is there any way i can traverse **two lists** in one go ?

Comment: I'm am not familiar with java (or play, for that matter).  Python (and various functional languages) have a function called `zip`, that can be used to do this.  Maybe that'll help point you in the right direction.

Comment: The thing is that I'm restricted to using java and play,so I'm really looking for a reply in that context. But thanks for responding.

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you want to do, in java you can construct an new Collection instance (ArrayList for example) from others with addAll for example, is what you want to do ?

Comment: @Kiran, I understand, I just thought that might help you search for a solution if you knew what it was called in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a single `INNER JOIN` is giving you performance issues? Your problem may lie elsewhere (lack of supporting indexes etc) as any modern rdbms can perform joins much faster than the alternatives. That being said, I'm not entirely sure a join is what you want.

Assuming I understad what you are asking when you say "merge the two lists and display in the UI." What you probably want is `UNION` (if you want the db to remove any duplicates between the lists) or `UNION ALL` if you just want the results of the two queries in one dataset.

Comment: We get millions of requests per day. Now imagine doing Inner Join everytime for all the records. The server might even crash.

Comment: I've developed databases that get about 4-6 million requests per hour, without breaking a sweat. Granted we weren't joining *all* the records (an average table was ~100+ million records), but working with appropriate datasets. I don't mean to be making assumptions but I have met many developers who think JOINs are bad and that baffles me, good SQL and schema (and a good dbms) and people should have no problems. All dbms are not created equal, but that's how relational databases are designed to work.